# Symfony 6 - Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine"

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I create a little application, i would like to update a database with a form. A have a error : **Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine"** in my controller. In my controller i have "use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;" and extends AbstractController of my class. I checked composer.json require i have : "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.5", and "doctrine/orm": "^2.10",

Can you help me ?
Thank's

the code :

```
 <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Produit;
use App\Form\ProduitType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;

class AdminController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/insert", name="insert")
     */
    public function insert(Request $request): Response
    {
        $produit = new Produit;
        $formProduit = $this->createForm(ProduitType::class,$produit);
        $formProduit->add('creer', SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'Insertion d\'un produit'));

        // Récupère les données dans l'entité
        $formProduit->handleRequest($request);

        // Teste l'existence de la méthode Post dans l'objet Request et teste la méthode isValid() qui contrôle
        // que toutes les données du formulaire vérifient les contraintes de validation.
        if($request->isMethod('post') && $formProduit->isValid()){

            // Récupère l'Entity Manager pour pouvoir insérer les données dans l'entité
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
...
```

Comment: Ok, good it's resolve ... : add use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;